# nm,objdump & pfunct giving contradicting answers to check if a function is inlined or not

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, objdump

i have a shared obj file say a.so and in that i want to see if a particular function (say fname) is inlined or not. I tried following 4 ways and getting different answers :

```
1) nm a.so | grep fname
```

-> this doesn't give any o/p implying that the function is inlined. 
Please let me know if this is sufficient check to see if a function is inlined or not.

```
2) objdump -d a.so | grep fname
```

->this doesn't give any o/p implying that the function is inlined. Please correct me if i am wrong in conclusion here.

```
3) objdump -W a.so
```

-> for function fname, this gives me the following o/p the last line of which says "declared as inline but ignored"

```
 DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x10411): fname
 DW_AT_decl_file   : 246
 DW_AT_decl_line   : 40
 DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
 DW_AT_inline      : 2      (declared as inline but ignored)
```

4) pfunct -G a.so | grep fname
->this dwarves utility shows the function fname implying that the function is not inlined.

Now first two ways imply that the function is inlined while rest two say the opposite. Can anyone please explain the following :

```
1) Why are there differences in the above 4 ways ? 
2) Are there any known issues with objdump and pfunct ? 
3) Also let me know the best way to check if a function is inlined or not.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: A function may be inlined in some places and not inlined in other ones. Is your function called at all in the .so?

Comment: yes, the function is static and called at only one place in that .c file

Comment: Was this shared obj file compiled with debug information? If not then a succesfully inlined function will have no evidence left around to say that it was ever a function at all.

Comment: yes .so is compiled with debug information

Comment: `Also let me know the best way to check if a function is inlined or not.` --- what if inspect code under `gdb`? You can create a test program and run it under `gdb`.

Comment: objdump -d is the best way to check if you have separated function definition. Some of you check actually read the dwarf debug information that includes also information for inlined functions. If language is C++ you have to remember that compiler mangles function names. Then -C parameter can help.

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is called at only one place in the .c file, the best way to check if the function is inlined is the following:

```
objdump -d a.so | grep call | grep fname
```

If there is any result, then `fname` is not inlined. Otherwise, it must be inlined because it is called at only one place and the call site in not found.

Comment: any explanation for why the difference in results using 4 approaches as above ?

Comment: The 4 approaches: 1) Output `fname`'s address when exists. 2) Output where `fname` is used in the code. It includes 1) and where `fname` is called. 3) Output the debugging information such as the defining line and file, its signature, etc. 4) I'm sorry I don't know about `pfunct`.

Comment: It seems that these days, `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d` does not write `call` in its output, so `grep call` in the above command will not really return anything; just `grep fname` seems to work ...